# Hibernate not logging to Log4J

Tags: hibernate, log4j

I have a tomcat app using hibernate. When I go into the WEB-INF and change the log4j.properties to the following...

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.SQL=trace
```

But I am not seeing anything in the log file I am using.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
....
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=hibernate.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Logging seems to work fine for my own app.

Any ideas?

Comment: check  your hibernate config xml file.Is there 'hibernate.show_sql' property is set to false ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure on this, but I think newer Hibernate-versions *might* use slf4j instead of log4j. You can get past this by using a slf4j-log4j -bridge. If you're using Maven, the dependency is along the lines of

```
    <!-- slf4j -> log4j bridge (some libraries use slf4j) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Modify versions as necessary.

Comment: I am using... <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.sli4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>sli4j-slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I'm not familiar with sli4j, but the website says "No setter methods are needed, no special annotations, just declare it and let sli4j doing the rest, final and already set Loggers will be skipped and sli4j won't try to override them at all.". Could the problem be that Hibernate loggers are declared as 'private static final', in which case sli4j won't inject its own loggers?

Comment: I tried adding this instead and I think it worked x2 checking

Answer (score 0):

Try the following because hibernate is no longer under a `net.sf` package hierarchy:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using an older version.

Comment: I think that when hibernate was under `net.sf` it wasn't yet using slf4j. Just wondering whether you really found the issue.